# Is there an ANSI/ISO Compliant Turbo C++?

Tags: c++98, turbo-c++

In my Computer Science Textbook (Britannica Live Wire Class 8 to be specific), the C++ IDE used is labeled and called under various instances as "Turbo C++" or "Turbo C++ IDE". It also uses fully ANSI/ISO (C++98 I believe) compliant C++ and runs natively on the Command Prompt on Windows 7 (I'm not sure of the bits). What's weird is that I researched for months on end but in vain. Does anyone know of such a version of Turbo C++? My school uses the run-of-the-mill Turbo C++ 3.0 in DOSBox and teaches us the old standard (the CBSE (India) syllabus still uses C++ from 1983). Can anyone please tell me if such a version exists and please provide a download/purchase link if so? Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Also look at these
[screenshots according to textbook.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFEep.jpg)

I have never seen any "Output" window in TC++. Also note the header on the screenshots: `#include <iostream.h>`. In the program examples given in the textbook, we always have `#include <iostream>` (note the lack of a `.h` extension).

Now the [program as printed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31FM5.jpg) (I included the image to prove I didn't copy it wrong)

When put into text, it is

```
// my first program in C++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
cout << "Hello Earth!\n";
cout<< "I love my country.\n";
return 0;
}
```

Note that in two particular programs `#include <iostream.h>` is used in the examples too along with `using namespace std;`. This is either

- Entirely Possible (A top Secret Project at Borland) (Highly Unlikely)
- Faked Screenshots and typo-ridden programs (Highly likely but weird for a textbook)

Can someone please enlighten me on this matter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't a simple "Hello World"-style program compile with Turbo C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. Turbo C++ is not C++98 compliant, and it was not developed since 2003, so there's no chance of ever getting a version.
C++11 and C++14 are of course also not existing.
I really don't get why Turbo C++ is used as a standard in India, it teaches an obsolete and cryptic style.
It might not help you with your syllabus, but I'd try gcc or clang, if you really want to learn C++ - both are open-source.

You can refer to this thread, for mor information, why Turbo C++ is a bad idea:
[Why not to use Turbo C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961828/why-not-to-use-turbo-c)

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, my book _still_ claims otherwise. Also CBSE has a weird liking for old software: VB6, TC++, Office 2003, Windows XP and the list goes on! I always use VS Community '15 or g++ for my learning at home, but convert it into TC++ in VMware before showing then to my teachers. I know it but this won't change soon. Many Indians **literally** relearn everything at work. Unfortunately, this is the way it is.