# Why doesn't a simple "Hello World"-style program compile with Turbo C++?

Tags: c++, turbo-c++, c++-faq

I have started learning C++ for my programming class. I have downloaded this "Hello World" program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    cout << "Hello, World!";
    return 0;
}
```

but Turbo C++ complains:

```
Error D:\HELLO.CPP 1: Unable to open include file 'IOSTREAM'
Error D:\HELLO.CPP 2: Declaration syntax error
Error D:\HELLO.CPP 6: Undefined symbol 'cout'
```

What's wrong with this very simple program? How can I correct these errors?

Comment: This is intended to be a standard dupe redirect for questions asking about Turbo C++ problems. Many of these questions tend to be shot down quickly with only a brief explanation in comments, while they can really use a proper answer. Improvements welcome.

Comment: suggest mentioning which release of Turbo C++ you are using.  The 2006 version coped with this program.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I found a way to copy and paste actual error messages ;)

Comment: @n.m. Great job thanks for your dedication in making an outstanding FA question.

Comment: "I have started learning C++ for my programming class.". This is a lie. Period.

Comment: @bugwheels94 [See this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-person_narrative).

Comment: @n.m. I don't know if bugwheells meant this, but I took them to mean that if one is taught *TurboC++* (in particular, old TurboC++ that fails to compile this), then they are not learning *C++* (which many people, me included, implicitly assume to mean *standard* C++).

Answer (score 171, accepted):

There's no problem with this program. (Except probably some stylistic issues —
`using namespace std` is not recommended). The problem is with Turbo C++. It is a very old piece of software. It implements a dialect of C++, so-called *pre-ANSI C++*, that has completely fallen out of use by the beginning of this millennium. The first ANSI standard for C++ was published in 1998, then there was the 2003 version, the 2011 version, the 2014 version, the 2017 version, and now we expect the 2020 version to be officially published. Each of these standard revisions brought more or less significant changes to the language.

For Turbo C++ you have to modify the program like this:

```
#include <iostream.h>      // note the .h suffix
// using namespace std;    // Turbo C++ doesn't implement namespaces

int main() 
{
    cout << "Hello, World!";
    return 0;
}
```

If you look at this program, the difference between the modern C++ dialect and the one accepted by Turbo C++ may seem small. However it will grow much larger as your programs will be getting more complex.

While you can learn programming using Turbo C++ I would strongly recommend to avoid that if humanly possible because of the following problems:

1. You will be learning a language that is somewhat similar to a popular language used in the industry, but is very different nevertheless, for no good reason. If you plan to write C++ for real software development, you will have to re-learn much. It is much easier to learn modern C++ right away.
2. There's no extant literature about Turbo C++. Nearly 100% of C++ material you will find on the internet or in the books is not directly applicable to Turbo C++ out of the box. Some will need only minor adaptation, while other material is completely unusable. Pretty much the only source of help immediately available to you is the built-in Turbo C++ help.
3. Few people remember Turbo C++. When asking questions on forums, always specify that you are using a pre-ANSI dialect in order to filter out responses geared towards the modern version of the language. You will probably get a bunch of comments suggesting you to stop immediately and switch to a modern compiler with every question you ask.

There are many modern free (as in [beer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeware), as well as in [speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software)) compilers and IDEs you can use in place of Turbo C++. Some of these include:

1. [Visual C++ Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) is an IDE and a compiler from Microsoft
2. [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is a lightweight IDE. On Windows it ships with a somewhat outdated compiler, but you can install a more modern compiler yourself
3. [Eclipse CDT](https://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) is a powerful cross-platform IDE. It doesn't ship with its own compiler so you need to install a separate compiler. On Windows, use e.g. [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).
4. [Many more](https://www.tecmint.com/best-linux-ide-editors-source-code-editors/)
5. In addition, there are many online compilers such as http://ideone.com, https://www.onlinegdb.com/ and http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/, plus [many more](https://www.google.com/search?q=online+c%2B%2B+compiler) (these are mostly good for trying out ideas and writing very small programs).
6. Both [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) and [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) compilers supporting recent versions of C++.

Regrettably, some schools/teachers appear to force students to use Turbo C++ even in this day and age. Unfortunately this is not something this community can fix. If you find yourself in this situation, prepare to not being able to get much outside help.

Comment: "There's no problem with this program." This can/is controversial though IMO. `using namespace std;`?

Comment: @Rakete1111 I think it's more in the sense of "This program contains no problem per the current standard." Whether it's good programming style is another thing.

Comment: @RickAstley In that case I would probably reword it, because I think it means that the code is ok on every level. But I'm not a native either..

Comment: @Rakete1111 there's nothing wrong with *responsible* use of `using namespace std`. It may or may not be a good pedagogical decision to teach it to new progammers, but it's not morally wrong per se.

Comment: Another issue with Turbo C++ is that the program written may compile/build successfully but uses graphics functions and other utilities that plain old won't work with a modern OS.

Comment: I agree completely with the idea that it is a bad idea to teach beginners to blindly use "using namespace std;"  I DO teach beginners to have a reason to include any features of the standard namespace and to do so deliberately using the scope resolution operator and the feature from the namespace.

Comment: I agree that `using namespace std` is bad practice, but I think it belongs in this question, because the C++ hello world programs you find online almost always do it.  So it's important to be clear that that isn't what's making Turbo C++ unhappy.  Perhaps instead of "There's no problem with this program" say "This program is valid, according to the _current_ C++ standard; it should compile."

Comment: This explains why I couldn't get Turbo C++ to work as a kid back in 2000.  It's nice to have closure!

Comment: Is "it will get much larger and as your program will get more complex" meant to read "it will get much larger as your program gets more complex"?

Comment: @hobbs As your programs get more complex, sorry.

Comment: This question caught my eye because as a student in 1999-2000 I took two C++ courses that taught pre-standards C++ using Turbo. I did well in the class and figured that I knew things pretty well. After getting out into the real world and seeing real code, I decided that I didn't know C++ at all, but at least I could parlay it into "I know C" :)

Comment: @n.m. All uses of `using namespace std;` are irresponsible, since you don't know what new identifiers will be added into the namespace, so you have no idea what conflicts might occur.

Comment: @Puppy by the same token, all calls to standard functions are irresponsible, because you don't know what new overloads will be added. You also don't know what language features will disappear from the next standard or change meaning. Not all programs need to live for decades or be portable to arbitrary compilers.

Comment: _"Few people remember Turbo C++"_ I disagree. At least one entire, large country is being actively taught it _today_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Indeed I see many questions about Turbo C++ hailing from one country. Not too many real Turbo-C++-specific answers though. Perhaps it's being taught but not learned that much, or this community is simply not representative enough.

Comment: Targeting real mode is one reason to stick with Turbo C++ over GCC. So I guess the follow-up question belongs on Software Recommendations: "Which ISO C++ compiler targets 16-bit 8088/286 real mode?"

Comment: @DamianYerrick I hear you can coerce the gcc toolchain into emitting 16-bit code.

Comment: @n.m.: In my experience, most C++ questions from that particular environment are swiftly closed ;)

Comment: @DamianYerrick [OpenWatcom](http://open-watcom.github.io/open-watcom/) is probably the most obvious choice other than GCC

Comment: Somewhere around Turbo C++ 4.x, the posted program compiled just fine. Even though it was released before C++98. I've added a post explaining the history of "Turbo C++", since there have been many different versions.

Answer (score 14):

"Turbo C++" can mean numerous compilers. When asking this question, it is important to include the version number.

- Borland Turbo C++ up to version 3.1 were pure MS DOS compilers in the classic blue background IDE. These were released roughly somewhere between 1989 to 1992, long before C++ had become standardized, which happened in the year 1998. And so they used a pre-standard dialect of C++.

  Most notably they used the `#include <iostream.h>` syntax rather than the standard `#include <iostream>`, but also didn't cover a whole lot of C++ features such as namespaces, templates etc. The template library STL was not part of the standard yet, so everything related to that library was pretty different from what later became standard.
- Later in the 90s, Borland released several DOS/Windows compilers with better conformance. Up to version 5 somewhere they still struggled with complete conformance to C++98, although these Windows versions were fairly close to it.
- In the late 90s, they dropped the name "Turbo C++" in favour for Borland C++ Builder, which was not just an IDE but a complete RAD tool based on Delphi. These compilers were fully compliant with C++98 and later C++03.
- Around 2005, Borland dropped compilers as part of their product line. The compilers became "Codegear", which later became Embarcadero. Somewhere around then, they released a free version of Borland Builder that they named "Turbo C++". This version was fully conforming to C++03.
- Nowadays these compilers are called Embarcadero C++ Builder. I believe they currently support up to C++11 with some C++14. [More info here.](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/evolution-of-c-standards)

Needless to say, as a student you should not use anything but modern compilers. Using MS DOS compilers from 1991 when learning C++ in the year 2018 is simply madness. Not only is it counter-productive, it is directly harmful and will make you a bad C++ programmer. If your school is forcing you to use Turbo C++ 3.1 or older, then your school is bad and your teachers are severely incompetent. Please link this post to them and their principal.

Comment: Turbo C++ is [still common in India in 2020](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bbc4RzTTLec&lc=Ugxcr1WrudpsLWHGeKh4AaABAg&t=1m40s). [More](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bbc4RzTTLec&lc=UgzdofiQp_1MkaYThgV4AaABAg) and [more](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bbc4RzTTLec&lc=UgzDUI_p2UmcsPT_FRF4AaABAg) - *"That's 40 years old outdated Turbo C. Indian colleges still teach it and refuse to teach anything else. They gave me zero marks, because I used `std::string` instead of `char *` in exams, because they don't know that C++ is standardized and `char *` is deprecated."*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yeah... it is somewhat ok for teaching C90 (amusingly, it is still better at that than Visual Studio from 2020), but the C++ dialect it used was just haywire.

Answer (score 6):

Turbo C++ is a very old compiler and it is a little bit different from the GNU C++ compiler. The code you shared will work perfectly with the GNU compiler but to run it with Turbo C++ you need to make a few changes:
1. Change the name of header file from `iostream` to `iostream.h`

2. And remove the line "using namespace std" It is not required in Turbo C++.
Here is the modified code:

```
#include <iostream.h>

int main() 
{
  cout << "Hello, World!";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does your answer add that the accepted one does not?

Comment: gist for the people who don't have time to read long answers.

Comment: it's not "a little bit different" but vastly different from C++ compilers