# size of array of integer pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
  int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
  int (*p)[5];
  int *p1[5];
  clrscr();

  printf("%d\n",(int)sizeof(a)); // 10
  printf("%d\n",(int)sizeof(p));  //2
  printf("%d\n",(int)sizeof(p1)); //10
  getch();
}
```

First output is 10 because each integer is of 2 bytes and hence 5 integers would take 10 bytes.

I am not able to understand the 3rd output which is 10. Here we have array of pointers each pointing to an integer. Size of pointer(or address) in my system is 32 bits (4 Bytes) . So the output should be 5*4=20 right as we have 5 pointers each of 4 bytes ?

Comment: Is this C or C++? Are you using Turbo C++ by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I am using Turbo C++

Comment: Verify with the size of a simple pointer to integer...

Comment: "Size of pointer(or address) in my system is 32 bits (4 Bytes)" - In that case your compiler is broken. Why do you assume that? Which is your system? Read [ask] and provide **all** required information. And `void main()` is an invalid signature -> `int main(void)`

Comment: Your system may be 32 bits, but TurboC++ came from the time before time when 16 bit compilers were all the rage.

Comment: @WeatherVane: OP states he uses TurboC++. Until further information it is more likely C++ (resp. that ancient dialect of TC++) than C.

Comment: @Olaf that is the name of the compiler. The code is C.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c

Comment: @user4581301: The first part is correct, TC++ is ancient. But back then there very well were 32 bit compilers, as there are still compilers for 16 and 8 bit CPUs (both are actually still the majority of devices).

Comment: @WeatherVane: The code can be either (I did not say it is good style).

Comment: @Olaf which is *more likely*? `clrscr();` was in the C library. Can you say it was in the C++ library?

Comment: @WeatherVane:I already answered that. Feel fre to ask on meta. Either way, OP apparently has lost interest helping himself. We are not here to spoon-feed lazy homeworkers. It is fine to get this closed.

Comment: That I will not argue, @olaf. Hell, I just spent part of the last week fixing 8-bit code on my whiz-bang 64 bit PC. But Turbo C++ targeted good ol' 16 bit DOS.

Comment: @hvd as I already said "TurboC++" is the **name** of the compiler.

Comment: @user4581301 While you were worokign around the quirks of "good ol' DOS", I used a 16/32 bit system with linear 32 bit programming model on my 68K ;-) I seriously question the "good" about DOS.

Comment: To hopefully bring this to an end: I VtC as "no mcve". Could be also "no error" or "unclear".

Comment: @hvd which comments suggest that, apart from assumptions about the compiler's name? There is **nothing in the code** that suggests it is C++. Many years ago, I used Borland Turbo C++ to produce both C and C++ code.

Comment: Stop using it and get yourself a compiler not made in the previous millennium.

Comment: @hvd the comments are pure speculation, you did not answer my question. From personal experience, the compiler makes C code and C++ code. If you use it to compile C code, that is what it does.

Comment: This discussion is taking a different path. Please answer my query which is under "LogicStuff's" answer.

Comment: @Xylene23 That's a new question. Make a new question to ask new questions. Better still, don't ask it. This should be covered in the first few chapters of any text book that isn't outright fraudulent.

Comment: @xylene23 there is a question in these comments you are ignoring; is your code compiled as c or c++?  (Turbo C++ can apparently compile code as either)

Comment: Your compiler is 16-bit, even if your host is 32-bit.    And, BTW, `main()` returns `int`, not `void` in C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second printout shows the size of a pointer on your machine is 2 bytes.
Array `int *p1[5];` has 5 elements, not 10.

5 * 2 = 10.

Comment: See my edit now. Size of pointer depends on the system right? In my case it is 32 bit so 4 bytes. So for an array containing 5 pointers, shouldn't the size of array be 5*4=20?

Comment: The second `printf` would print `4` if that was true.

Comment: In the pointer array, what will be the increment size? Will it be according to the type which it is pointing to (int in this case) or according to the size of pointer which is 16 bits or 2 bytes ?

Comment: It will be `sizeof(int *)`.

Comment: All it says is a pointer takes two bytes. That does not say anything about the width of a byte, though.

Comment: @Olaf Suppose the starting address of p array is 200. Then will the address of p[1] be 202 because the size of pointer is 2 bytes or is it because size of integer is 2 bytes?

Answer (score 2):

> Size of pointer(or address) in my system is 32 bits

Turbo C++ is an MS-DOS program. It's unable to run on a modern OS directly. Your OS creates, in a way completely transparent to you, an emulated 16-bit MS-DOS machine to run your outdated stuff on. So no, the size of pointers on your (emulated) system is 16 bits. You are using a 16-bit system.

Turbo C++ is actually capable of using 32-bit pointers if you switch code generation to "large" or "huge" mode. The system is still a 16-bit one, it just has a weird addressing scheme with "long" pointers.

On a side note, using Turbo C++ in this current millennium is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c) (warning: shameless plug).

Answer (score 1):

## You are on a 16 bit system

All three numbers are consistent with each other. But you seem to be using a 16 bit system. So your pointers use 2 bytes. And 5 elements times 2 bytes each equals 10 bytes in total.

Comment: I am not using a 16 bit system but still turbo C++ shows that it's 16 bit. I don't know the reason behind that.

Comment: @Xylene23 it might be that your system can process 32 bit numbers in hardware. But your pointers use 2 byte (which is 16 bit). So I think it is called a 16 bit system (actually by definition).

Comment: @Xylene23 Turbo C++ was built to compile programs that would run on a 16 bit operating system. It doesn't know that anything other than 16 bit addressing exists. Your much more advanced computer and operating system are kind enough to hide the existence of the other 16 bits from the programs you compile with Turbo C++ and allow them to run.