# Turbo C++ compiler not reading text file properly. (Only when I make it a .dat file, is it read properly)

Tags: c++, fstream, file-management, turbo-c++

I am facing a problem with C++ and C, where my ifstream object, or file pointer is not reading a text file properly, and displays illegal characters when output. However, when I read a .dat file, it outputs the correct result.

This is the C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
void main() {
    FILE *file;
    char ch;
    file = fopen("code.dat", "r");
    while((ch = getc(file)) != EOF)
        printf("%c", ch);
    getch();
    fclose(file);
}
```

This is the CPP code:

```
#include <fstream.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    clrscr();
    fstream file;
    file.open("code.dat", ios::in);
    char ch, c;
    char token[6];
    int id = 0, op = 0, key = 0;
    while (!file.eof()) {
        file >> ch;
        if(ch == ' ') {
            if ((ch > 64 && ch < 91) || (ch > 96 && ch < 123))
                id += 1;
        }
    }

    cout << id;
    file.close();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Turbo C++ is an ancient compiler, with discontinued support. It uses a dialect of C++ from before the standardization of the language. If you want to learn C++, the way it's used toady, upgrade to something modern. GCC and Clang are good options.

Comment: "I am facing a problem with C++ and C, where my ifstream object" - You don't. C does not have an "ifstream object". It is a completely different language!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't a simple "Hello World"-style program compile with Turbo C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c)

Comment: @Olaf The file pointer for C, and ifstream object for C++.. I know that much bro..

Comment: @AkhileshIyer: Well, you at least seem not to knwo [ask]. (Oh, and: I'd appreciate if you refrain from using street-slang … "bro").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are having problems with text file, try opening it in binary mode, ie:adding ios::binary. So the code becomes:

```
file.open("code.txt",ios::in|ios::binary);
```

Also file>>ch is used when you want to read an entire word. Since you want to read character by character try

```
file.get(ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

A potential issue could be in the code:

```
if(ch == ' ')
{
    if((ch > 64 && ch < 91) || (ch > 96 && ch < 123))
        id += 1;
}
```

The outer `if` statement excludes the possibility of the inner `if` statement executing (ASCII code for a space is 32, so `ch` can't be both 32 and satisfy one of the two conditions, so `id` is never incremented).

This doesn't seem like it would produce the behaviour you're describing though, it should just result in printing `0` to `stdout`.

It's hard to know what's going wrong without an example of output - we need an [MCVe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to provide good advice. Here, your C code just prints the contents of the file, whereas the C++ code counts the number of alphabet characters (maybe, I just skimmed over it). So which one fails? And how? Give us an **example of the output**, and **clarify what you expected** each one to do.

As others have mentioned, Turbo C++ is outdated - you should start using g++ or clang instead.