# How to execute a while-loop for exactly 60 seconds in C++?

Tags: c++, while-loop

Does anyone know how can I run this loop for 60 seconds and then stop? Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    clrscr();
    int a=1;
    int b;
    cout<<"3.";
    b=a*10%7;
    while(b!=0)
    {
        cout<<a/7;
        a=b*10;
        b=a%7;
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? a delay?

Comment: Create a `startTime` variable and check it every iteration of the `while` loop. If the `startTime` was more than 60 s in the past, `break`.

Comment: @Xirema It seems TurboC++, given iostream.h and conio.h

Comment: You can't run it for "exactly" 60 seconds. Checking the current time can give you "at least 60 seconds". How much precision do you need? Seconds, milliseconds, micro?..

Comment: check out the <time.h> header

Comment: Please update your development environment. All of the top of the line compilers are free.

Comment: You are not using C++. You are using a much older language, now totally obsolete and unsupported, that was called C++ circa 20 years ago when it was popular. A language we call C++ now is very different from what you are using. For more information see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c/44863063#44863063) (warning: shameless plug).

Answer (score 7):

Use the `<chrono>` library.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<chrono>

int main()
{
    clrscr();
    int a=1;
    int b;
    std::cout<<"3."; //Don't use 'using namespace std;'...
    b=a*10%7;
    std::chrono::time_point start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    while(b!=0)
    {
        std::cout<<a/7;
        a=b*10;
        b=a%7;
        if(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start > std::chrono::seconds(60)) 
            break;
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you think a user of iostream.h will appreciate this answer?

Comment: Although if his standard library has a header called `<iostream.h>`, I doubt it has `<chrono>`. (not to say, of course, that there is anything wrong with this answer, as it will be useful to other users)

Comment: conio.h is not part of the stl and obsolete now in 2023. It will also give a compilation error on a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

Before you start the loop get the time. Add 60 seconds. Each time through the loop get the time and compare it to your target time. Has it been 60 seconds? If so, stop.

Look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono for the C++ library header.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for (auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(), now = start; now < start + std::chrono::seconds{60}; now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now()) 
{}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one working example using chrono

```
#include<iostream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a=1;
    int b;
    cout<<"3.";
    b=a*10%7;

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    while((std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end - start).count() != 60))

    {
        end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        cout<<"Time is"<<std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end - start).count()<<" second"<<endl;

        cout<<a/7<<endl;
        a=b*10;
        b=a%7;
    }
}
```

Output (part of output)

```
4
Time is59 second
2
Time is60 second
8
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make sure a loop doesn't execute subsequent times after 60 seconds with time.h!

```
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

clock_t start = clock();
while ( (clock() - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC <= 60)
    //do stuff here
```

This is essentially grabbing the number of clocks at the current time and assigning it to `start`. After that, each iteration of the loop, it is checking if the difference between the current clock and the `start` clocks, divided by a factor of clocks per second for conversion, is less than or equal to your desired 60 seconds.

Comment: Where is CLOCKS_PER_SECOND defined? Please.

Comment: @GaryCarlyleCook Don't fall for this. It's called CLOCKS_PER_SEC defined in time.h

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that just insert a time check in the loop.
Since *C++11* you can use [chrono standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

The idea is the one shown in the [following code snippet](https://ideone.com/LwuRku).

I designed the function in a template in order to be more generic and show only the conditional loop with the timer.

That is:

```
template <std::int64_t Seconds, typename Fn, typename... Args>
void repeat_for_seconds(Fn&& fn, Args&&... args) {
  using ClockType = std::chrono::system_clock;

  // Time at the start of the function
  auto time_start = ClockType::now();

  while (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(ClockType::now() -
                                                          time_start)
             .count() < Seconds) {
    /* execute code you want in the while loop */
  }
}
```

Because *ideone policies* the snippet has a delay of 3 seconds, but you can easily change it in the first template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to register a signal handler for 60 seconds.

Below is a sample program to use signal handler:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define INTERVAL 60             // number of seconds to go off

void sigTimerStop(int signum) {
    printf("Timer ran out! Stopping timer\n");
}

void sigTimerSet(int interval) {
    printf("starting timer\n");
    struct itimerval it_val;

    it_val.it_value.tv_sec = interval;
    it_val.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    it_val.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    it_val.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;

    if (signal(SIGALRM, sigTimerStop) == SIG_ERR) {
        perror("Unable to catch SIGALRM");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &it_val, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("error calling sigsetitimer()");
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    sigTimerSet(INTERVAL);

    while (1) {
        // do stuff
    }
    return 0;
}
```