# Why is Turbo C++ showing this error in DOSBox on my Mac?

Tags: turbo-c++, dosbox

I don't understand why it couldn't recognise `#include <iostream.h>`.
I have mounted it in my C drive

The link for the image of the error is here:

The error it shows:

[image]

What does "Unable to create output file mean?

[ERROR 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfXEB.png)
[ERROR 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wntq0.png)

Comment: My school wants me to use turbo c++

Comment: It's <iostream>, but really using Turbo C++ is a death trap.

Comment: Then your school is incompetent unless they want to show you how it was before standardization.

Comment: I understand that
I use Xcode but i have to submit an assignment and it has to be done on Turbo c++

Comment: So, do u know how to fix it?

Comment: Your school is so seriously behind the times it is unbelievable.  Turbo C++ wasn't a good choice at any time in the current millennium.  It is a far worse choice since C++11 and C++14 have been released.  It was already archaic — headers like `<iostream.h>` are pre-standard C++.  The language recognized by Turbo C++ is barely related to modern C++.  Much of what you're learning will need to be relearned differently as soon as you're out of school.  You should find a better school.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't a simple "Hello World"-style program compile with Turbo C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler no offense but in third world countries, students are taught programming in Turbo C++ in almost all the colleges so they have no other choices. Besides, in the future they will be taught how to use functions from graphics.h. That's another reason why they are forced to use it.

Comment: @Zindagi did you look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c ?

Comment: @Asesh: I know that it is prevalent.  It is not helping anyone that it is prevalent.  And there are equally cheap and far more modern compilers available.  I think that it is a gross abuse of the term 'educational institution' for anyone to be teaching with Turbo C++ anywhere in the world.

Comment: Guys, please stick to helping answer the question, no need to go off topic here, there's chat for that

Comment: Does anyone have a proper solution for the question???

Comment: @Valentin - The rest of us stopped using Turbo-C++ well before 1995, when it was discontinued. We simply don't remember the hacks we had to use before that.

Comment: iis your **TC++** located at `c:\TC` ? if not you need to change the paths in the config of **TC++**. Do you got write access for files? if **DOS-BOX** `C:` drive is mapped to place where **OSX** prohibits write access by **DOS-BOX** .... Also do you got the C++ engine and libs at `c:\TC\lib` and `c:\TC\include`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Installation must be faulty!
I've a mac, in fact, I'm currently running TurboC++ on it as I type. Consider uninstalling and then reinstalling.

[Download Here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/turbo-for-mac/)

Download the package just like you would download a .dmg application from the net. (i.e. Drag and dropping the application into the Applications folder)
Make sure that your Applications folder is global with respect to your system. What I mean is that:

- Click on the "GO" option in the menu bar on top when in Finder.
- Select "Computer" from the drop down menu.
- Now click on your hard drive in the new window that opened.
- You will find an "Applications" folder there. Thats where your TurboC++ should be.

Note: The TurboC++ you download from the link above will be a folder inside which you will find many other folders and the application: TurboC++, which is actually DosBox. One of the important folder is TC which contains the BIN folder where your source codes will be stored.

Go to Launchpad, and start Turbo C++. Then type the following commands:

```
mount c: /Applications/TurboC++
<press enter>
c:
<press enter>
cd tc
<press enter>
cd bin
<press enter>
tc
```

It is case sensitive so be careful.

This is how it should look:
[image: This is how it should look]

Comment: Please Mark my Answer, on the left if it helped you and solved the issue you were facing.

Comment: Hey @Alpha Mineron ,

Comment: I followed all the steps you have written above but when I typed cd tc it said

Comment: "Unable to change to: tc" , do u have a solution for that?
And thanks a lot for your help, I have already marked ur answer as helpful as you have made an effort to help me :)

Comment: @Zindagi Could you edit your question and put a screenshot?

Comment: Sure! Its in the link name ERROR 2 in my question

Comment: @Zindagi The problem is that the 'c' drive is already mounted to some Apple folder. Try using another name, use 'f'.

Comment: There is one last error when I change it to drive 'f'. I have sent a screenshot in ERROR 3 in my question

Comment: @Zindagi Ugh, That's new! This might help you: https://community.embarcadero.com/article/technical-articles/162-programming/14160-application-load-and-execute-error

Comment: @Zindagi I'll suggest, asking another question on a appropriate Stack Exchange site. Maybe, post on SO with the tags dosbox. This question has now diverted from the Launching TurboC++ to a memory issue in Dosbox

Comment: Damn, thats sad...
Anyway, Thanks for ur help!