# What are the differences between Turbo C++ 7 and Dev C++ in terms of syntax?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++98

In school I was taught C++ using Turbo C++ 7 . When I entered college , I found out that it was out dated . I would like to know the changes which have been implemented in C++ 14 in GCC or Dev C++ compiler.

Example : **conio.h** does not exist in C++98, C++14 etc. instead we have `using namespace std;` .

Comment: This is almost like someone locked in a bunker for the past 20 years going outside just now. Ouch.

Comment: of a very much interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz hehe. at least he got to learn coding in "school" (dunno if primary or high school or what part of the world...) in a very **unforgiving language**... his knowledge is probably above the "I toyed with Python/Javascript, now gimme my well payed job" folks :)

Comment: What you're asking for fills many books. We can't give you a  full answer

Comment: Btw., DevC++ is no compiler (and never was one)

Comment: Read http://norvig.com/21-days.html for a useful insight

Comment: There are literally entire books about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you say (and reference to `conio.h`), the most likely conclusion is that **you were not taught C++** (using Turbo C++ 7). You were taught "C with some C++ features sprinkled over". What some ambiguously call "C/C++". That's what most learn in good high schools, and it can serve you well through coding competitions.

So follow these steps:

1. accept that you *don't know C++* (or that "what you know is not real C++")
2. go over the introductory "[A Tour of C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/Tour.html)" from Bjarne Stroustrup, the guy who *created C++*, and fill in the gaps between "what you know" and "modern C++"
3. read a bit about the differences between the language features of various C++ standard versions (start by google-ing "C++14 features" etc.)
4. pick a good C++ book, like maybe "Effective C++" (or others, ask around a bit!) and go through it alongside your courses in the first few years of college

*Tip:* Somewhere between 3 and 4, when you'll realize it's going to take you years and years to master C++, stop and ask yourself *"is C++ the right language for the kinds of programs I want to write?".* If the answer is "no", pick something else. If the answer is "yes", then pause and take some detours: a couple detours to the "underworlds" of assembler and "real plain C" (the type you find in Linux's kernel), and a couple detours to the "alternative universes" of D, Rust and Go, to understand *what's wrong with C++ and why it's responsible for most of the world's bugs and security holes* (hint: there's a lot wrong!), and how to mitigate its anti-features.

Oh, and... don't despair :)

Comment: SInce you started with comparing languages here ... `there's a lot wrong` Yes. However, you don't want a OS kernel in Go either. `why it's responsible for most of the world's bugs` Divide that with the usage share (eg. how many SLOC run on how many computers worldwide), then it's great.

Comment: @deviantfan ok, Go is bad one there, it's not a "systems language" for real. but Rust and D are, though I imagine that the only real competitor for C++ is "the next version of C++", too much old code that needs to be maintained and reused :)

Comment: This seems highly opinionated and off topic. OP is not asking how to learn C++, and even moreso they did not ask about alternatives to C++, nor your review of the language. A statement that C++ is responsible for "most of the worlds bugs and security holes" is over the top and pretty meaningless in this context (i.e. unqualified and without links to any backing resources).

Comment: @NirFriedman what's the fun of answering such a question if you can't side-troll a bit while doin' it? :)

Answer (score 4):

Notice that `<conio.h>`  does not exist in any programming language standard. You could check with the [C11](http://ttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) draft standard on [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). You could check with the [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++14) standard too (and you could check with all earlier standards of C or of C++). FWIW, I'm coding since the 1970s and never used `<conio.h>`

I'm using a good, very standard conforming, implementation of C11 and of C+14 and it has no `<conio.h>`. My computer runs Linux and my compiler is [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) 7.

The [`<conio.h>`  header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) is specific to MicroSoft systems.  AFAIK no standard mentions it. You won't find `<conio.h>` on POSIX (and all non-MicroSoft) systems (you should prefer [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) for POSIX, it is a free software library commonly used). Even 1990s era Unix workstations did not have
`<conio.h>` and current non-Microsoft systems don't have them.

[TurboC++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B) is an obsolete compiler. It compiled an obsolete, never standardized, variant of a subset of C++. **Don't use TurboC++** today!

BTW, [DevC++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev-C%2B%2B) (or [Code::Blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code::Blocks)) are *not* compilers, but [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s. They are running some (configurable) compiler, often  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/).

I strongly recommend using some *recent* [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) C++ compiler, notably [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/). Both are very standard conforming (with some *tiny* documented deviations).

Don't forget to enable all warnings and debug info (most compilers don't enable them by default). With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`.

I even very strongly recommend installing some [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) on your computer, because they are very developer friendly and made of free software whose source code you can study.

If you want to learn C++, be sure to learn and use at least [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) (and preferably C++14, which is very close to C++11). Any older standard is not worth learning (unless your employer forces you to) in 2017.

Of course, a C++ compiler alone is not enough (BTW nearly all of them are command line programs). You also need other tools, notably linkers and loaders and assemblers (e.g. [binutils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Binutils)); you need some [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) (my preference is [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) but you could use [vim](http://vim.org/) or [gedit](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit) or many others) - some of them call themselves [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s - and you want to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) (such as [GNU `gdb`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)), a version control system (I recommend [git](http://git-scm.com/)), a [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (like [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)).

Most Linux distributions are packaging all that very nicely.

Once you have read a good [introduction to C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/), take the habit to look on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/). Be aware that **C++ is a *very complex* programming language** (and few people know it very well, I don't claim to know it well and probably never met any person knowing it very well), so prepare yourself to spend several years learning it. An important notion is that of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

BTW, the most important differences between the language accepted by TurboC and the C++14 standard are not syntactic, but [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)).