# Re-execute old c++ programs on new version of c++ compilers

Tags: c++

I worked at the Master's study in 2000 in the field of optimization to compare three different programming techniques to solve the assignment problem that is one of operational research problems

The first technique
was  speed up the enumeration method to get the optimum solution
The second technique
Using the Hankaryan method
Third technique
Using the genetic algorithm

I programmed all the above techniques in C ++
This was in 1999 on a Pentium 1 computer and by using Borland C++ version 3, I compared the results of these techniques depending on three criteria:
1-  Optimality of the result.
2-  Required memory allocation.
3-  Required time to get the result.
**My question is....
I want to re-execute these above programs now on (i7 CPU) computer with Windows 8, But programs did not execute on the Borland C ++ version 5
How can I solve the problem?**

Comment: Some error messages to share ?

Comment: Upgrade to compiler that is of this decade and fix the errors.

Comment: Borland C++ V5 is 20 years old and has not been updated (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_C%2B%2B )  Please conciser updating to a compiler that is currently maintained.  This question contains a lot of relevant information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c

Comment: Thank you too much, dear Pete Becker .... can you advise me with the new modern version for  C++ compiler that is more convenient to Borland C++ V5 with a download link to this compiler ... thanks too much dear