# How to access functions and data from one turbo c++ program to the other?

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I, want to make a program for an organisation as an assignment in turbo c++,So **what I thought of was to create separate c++ programs for separate jobs** (since everything combined as one program becomes huge.Now assume that i have created 2 turbo c++ programs,**a.cpp** and **b.cpp**.Now how do i access the data (**especially functions, classes** )from a and b into a new program **c.cpp** 
here .cpp are the extension of c++ programs.

Comment: Step 1: Don't use Turbo C++

Comment: I agree with your statement, but my school demands the assignment to be done in turbo c++

Comment: Please read before asking about Turbo C++ [we don't know because it is so old]:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c

Answer (score 0):

For doing this we need to use #include"filename".
And include the path of your program in the directory.Now we can just write #include"a.cpp" and #include"b.cpp",in an other program c.cpp,then we will be able to access the functions in a.cpp as well as b.cpp from c.cpp.