# GALIB 242 open source software written in C++ for genetic algorithms - linker errors

Tags: c++, genetic-algorithm

[image]

I downloaded the GALIB 242 open source software developed by MIT( coded in C++ language for a variety of genetic algorithms), and tried to run on a TurboC7 IDE. I was successful in compiling the program(i.e., no errors in compiling). but around 9 linker errors i got when i tried to run the program EX1.cpp of GALIB242 software. I am attaching the screenshot of the error message

Comment: Try using a proper compiler. [Why doesn't a simple "Hello World"-style program compile with Turbo-C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c)

Comment: @BoPersson The 2.4.2 version is from 1996 and should work with even older Turbos, according to the README.

Comment: Did you build the library and are you linking with it?

Comment: The GALIB contains a number of headers, sources, and examples. I copied all the header files of GALIB in to the header file location of TURBOC7. Then, i tried to open EX!.CPP of GALIB by opening it in TURBOC7. There were no compiling errors. But the same EX1.CPP when i tried to run gave 9 linker errors. as shown in the image

Comment: I want to run EX1.CPP