# Create a TAnimate in Borland 2006

Tags: c++, jquery-animate, vcl

I have the following problem. I am using the Borland 2006 Compiler and I am trying to include an animation in my applicaton. First I added the TAnimate Object and then in the ObjectInspector under "FileName", every time I try to add an .avi, the Compiler says "AVI cannot be opened". Am I doing something wrong or isn't it that simple to just put a .gif or .avi into that Objectproperty?

Edit // Here ist Some CodeExample, everytime i press the button, it throws an exception and tells me that the avi File cannot be opened

```
void __fastcall THauptmenue_Login::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
Animate1->FileName = ("C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Desktop\\C++ Gifs");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't a simple "Hello World"-style program compile with Turbo C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c)  See the 1st answer on more up to date compilers.  Trying to offer help for a 10 year old, non-standard, no longer supported compiler is difficult.  Also please make a [mcve] for your question.

Comment: Problem is we are using this compiler in our school, so doing it with something else is kinda double the work for me.

Comment: I've spotted your problem: "I am using the Borland 2006 Compiler". Just *don't* do that. Almost anything you are going to learn with that compiler is going to be obsolete or just plain wrong in modern C++, so you are not actually learning anything useful with it that you can use in todays job-market.

Answer (score 1):

The FileName you showed doesn't look complete. It looks more like a path to a folder instead of a file.

In the Object Inspector, beside the `FileName` text box is a [...] button which brings up a file browser dialog which can add a full path and name to a file.

addendum:
If you are using the Object Inspector to *pick* a filename from the disk you do not need to specify a `FileName` property value in the code.

This overwrites any previous `FileName` property value.

```
Animate1->FileName = "C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Desktop\\C++ Gifs";
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, yes thats what i tried to explain in my post above, when i try this i get this avi error all the time and i dont know how to fix it

Comment: Have you run the Avi file in Windows Explorer? Have you right-clicked on the Avi file and looked at its properties? Can you try to move or copy the file to the same directory as the executable (Application), and then set the FileName _property_ manually?

Comment: i can do all the things you described, and copied it to the same directory but still doesnt work :(

Comment: Edited the above post.