# Validation not going properly

Tags: c++

When I enter a character as input, it goes into infinite loop. I am unable to validate anything properly I am not able to find whats going wrong.
and if you enter 2 or  more chars, the program exits on its own.

```
//The Following Program Converts Decimal into Binary
#include <iostream.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <process.h>

#define size 8 //change this to change output from 8bit to more or less.

int main()
{
    int dnum;   //Decimal Number to be converted
    char ch;
    do{
    clrscr();
    int i=0,j, ar[size]={0};     //i and j for loop
     do{
        cout<<"Enter Number to convert to binary of:";
        cin>>dnum;
        if(dnum>=256 || isalpha(dnum))
        {
            cout<<"\nEnter number less than 256 only:";
            cin>>dnum;
        }
        else
        break;
        }while(dnum>256);
    dnum+=256;  //trick

    while(dnum>0)        //Process to divide by 2 and store in array
    {
        ar[i]=dnum%2;
        dnum/=2;
        i++;
    }
    for(j=(i-2); j>=0; j--) //Print array in opposite way
    {       if(j==3)
        cout<<" ";
        cout<<ar[j];
    }
    cout<<"\nWanna Find Again?(y/n)";
    cin>>ch;
    }while(ch=='y'||ch=='Y');
    return 0;
}
```

[The Output Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AN1V.png)

Comment: This is a totally bad program. `iostream.h` us nonsense and you shouldn't have tagged it with `c`.

Comment: When `cin >> dnum` fails (e.g. when the input does not form a valid integer), `dnum` is left an uninitialized variable. Accessing its value with `dnum > 256` then exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: so, do I initialize it with 0?

Comment: I corrected a few fundamental mistakes for you.

Comment: you dont need to edit this. I am learning with GCC compiler right now, it needs ".h" at the header files's ending.

Comment: What version of GCC requires `<iostream.h>`?  Note -- no version does.

Comment: I've never heard that there's an include file named `iostream.h` or `ctype.h`. They're either obsolete or totally mistaken.

Comment: Also, GCC won't accept C++-style input and output. You're probably using `g++`, which AFAIK should have warned about you or even give errors.

Comment: @iBug -- g++ as of 1998 and maybe before that, uses `<iostream>`.  I have no idea what the OP is talking about, saying that `<iostream.h>` is required for gcc.  The code looks like a Turbo C++ antique.

Comment: its really old compiler and yes i am using Turbo C++

Comment: If you want to read a line of input and then check to see if it's a valid number, why not write code that does that?

Comment: @UdayPatel -- Then the issue is that whatever answer you may get may not work, since the answers given assume you're using a modern. ANSI standard C++ compiler that adheres to the rules of standard streaming classes.

Comment: Unrelated but helpful reading: [Why doesn't a simple “Hello World”-style program compile with Turbo C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c)

Comment: thats what i meant before, thanks @user4581301

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `dnum` is an integer, `cin` will refuse to read if it encounters anything that's not an integer (e.g. `aaa`). You can check if `cin` has failed:

```
cin >> dnum;
while (cin.fail() || cin.eof()) {
    if (cin.eof()){
        // No more input available. Exit as exception.
        exit(1);
    }
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
    // Print a prompt that the input was wrong.
    cin >> dnum;
}
```

This way you're guaranteed that a valid number will be read.

Comment: Yes, This is working. but, I have to limit input under 256, where do i add that condition?

Comment: Just add the value range check into the loop condition: `while (cin.fail() || cin.eof() || (dnum < 0 || dnum >= 256))`

Comment: Minor niggle: `exit` is overkill for a program that consists entirely of `main`. Can I talk you into `return 1;`?

Comment: @user4581301 In case the author migrates this code into another function.