# Program fails when linking a mix of C and assembly files with Turbo-C++ 3.0 tools

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, masm, turbo-c++

I have the following assembly code which is aimed to set the screen mode to mode 13:

```
.model small
.code

public _func

_func proc
        mov al,13h
        int 10h
    ret
_func endp
END
```

it's assembled successfully into an object file main.obj
now I am trying to call the public _func from the following C code :

```
extern void func();

int main() {

    func();
    return(0);
}
```

but I have no idea how to link the two objects to produce a working exe
I googled much , but most of the posts are in GCC compiler

I have tried the following command line :
tcc cmain.c main.obj

I got the exe file CMAIN.EXE
but it doesn't change the mode to mode 13
it just displays the message "Abnormal program termination"

I am using turbo c++ 3.0 compiler and masm5.11 assembler
what is the proper command to get it work ?

Comment: Don't TurboC++, it is obsolete. Use some recent, C++14 compliant, free software compiler ([GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvvm.org/)...)

Comment: [More about using Turbo-C++ (or not)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I didn't see until I wasted a lot of time is that you have an error in the code:

```
mov al,13h
int 10h
ret
```

You don't actually set *AH* to 0 for the [Video Mode Set subfunction of INT 10h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0069.htm). Your code attempts to call [`Int 10h`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-10.htm) with an arbitrary value in *AH* left over from earlier instructions. The code should look like this:

```
xor ah, ah    ; AH=0 Set Video Mode
mov al,13h    ; Video Mode 13h
int 10h
ret
```

Or simply:

```
mov ax, 0013h ; AH = 0h Video Mode Set, AL = Video Mode 13h
int 10h
ret
```

To get this to assemble and compile with MASM and TCC I had to split compiling and linking with:

```
masm main.asm;
tcc -Ic:\tcpp\include -ms -c cmain.c
tlink c0s cmain.obj main.obj,chgmode.exe,,cs -Lc:\tcpp\lib
```

`c:\tcpp\include` and `c:\tcpp\lib` have to be replaced with the the directories appropriate for your environment so TCC and TLINK can find the include files and libraries. `c0s` and `cs` are the C runtime startup object and library for the SMALL memory model. Replace the last letter with the letter appropriate for the memory model you need to build for.

- `c0t` and `ct` for tiny
- `c0s` and `cs` for small
- `c0c` and `cc` for compact
- `c0m` and `cm` for medium
- `c0l` and `cl` for large
- `c0h` and `ch` for huge

The TCC command line sets the memory model as well for each *C* file you compile `-ms` is for SMALL memory model. Change the last letter similar to above.

Effectively this process compiles the *C* files and assembly files to individual object files and then links them all together in the last step.

Comment: Thank you Michael , after I made the changes you had suggest, it's worked now , however the message ("Abnormal program termination") is still displayed . whats wrong ?

Comment: Well , after using  mov ah, 4ch int 21h , the message was disappeared

Comment: @Howard : If you still have an abnormal program termination and had to fix it by making your assembly function terminate you still have ia serious problem. Besides  a different LIB and IInclude path did you do the **exact** steps in the answer? It sounds to me the C library is wrong. I used MASM 5.10 and TC++3.0. You say you are using MASM 5.11.Can you confirm that by running your MASM (version should appear at the top)?

Comment: @Howard : If you try to use `tcc` to compile and link at the same time it may not work which was why I split the steps out.

Comment: Sure i'm sure from the versions I have described above , and like I said I have solved the problem by using the mov ah, 4ch int 21h which terminate the program and exit to dos . thank you again for your concern.