# Getting error while run the program in C language

Tags: c, turbo-c++

[image]Getting warning each time while run the program in C.

Comment: It's 2018 now. Turbo C++ is from 1990s.

Comment: Don't bother. And don't use TurboC. This software is most likely older than you.

Comment: Tightly related: [Why doesn't a simple “Hello World”-style program compile with Turbo C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c) . Basically you're using the computer equivalent of a Bronze Age tool. It does not work well on modern computers.

Comment: It probably thinks the file's timestamp is in the future. Try saving it again?

Comment: Which editor should i use for C/C++?

Comment: Basically anything you want. If you want to learn and not deal with compiling, something like Eclipse CDT will do well. A text editor and g++ will do just as well, and you have more control. I'm curious where you got that you should use Turbo C++.

Comment: `gcc` and `clang` are good open-source compilers you can use.

Comment: C++ has come a long way since 1987.

Comment: This question is liable to **downvotes** mainly because Turbo-C++ is considered obsolete and no longer relevant.

Comment: This warning comes after you finish running the file and didn't save it before you started compiling it.

Answer (score 4):

This is not **Error** this is just a **Warning** .

**Save** the file every time before you *Build* and *Run*. This is the solution to your warning.This warning happens when you *edit* the program and tries to *run* it without *saving*.

Also your `IDE Turbo C++` is very outdated Programming environment.I recommend [CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) . *Code::Blocks* is a free `C`, `C++` and `Fortran IDE` built to meet the most demanding needs of its users. It is designed to be very extensible and fully configurable.You can [download it from here](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are running this application in some sort of emulator. 
Restart the program and try running that.
It should work.
Turbo C is terribly out of date and is probably even older than you.
I suggest you to upgrade to a IDE like Code::Blocks.
If, you are a beginner I suggest you compile using GCC command line compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Save the file before you run/compile your code.