# Compiles in turbo c++. Not in visual studio

Tags: c++

I always get this error:

> "Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2371   'FILE': redefinition; different basic types ConsoleApplication2 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h   28
>   "

Why?
It used to compile in TurboC++.
Not in Visual Studio.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "iostream.h"
#include "conio.h"
class ari
{       public:
       //   int a;
    //int b;
    //int c;
    int add (int a,int b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }
    int sub (int a,int b)
    {
        return a-b;
    }
    int mul (int a, int b)
    {
        return a*b;
    }
    int div (int a, int b)
    {
        return a/b;
    }
};
class log
{       public:
       //   int a,b;
    int gre (int a, int b)
    {
        if (a>b)
            return a;
        else
            return b;
    }
    int sma (int a, int b)
    {
        if (a>b)
            return b;
        else
            return a;
    }

};
class gra
{       public:
    //int w, b, c, k,a;
    void unline()
        {
            cout << "\n\n";
            for (int k=0 ; k<80 ; cout << "_", k++);
            cout << "\n\n";
        }
    void wait (int w)
        {
            //cout << "\n\n";
            for (long long long long int a=0 ; a<(w*100000) ; a++ );
            //cout << "\n\n";
        }
    void asline()
        {
            cout << "\n\n";
            for (int k=0 ; k<80 ; cout << "*", k++);
            cout << "\n\n";
        }
    void hiline()
        {
            cout << "\n\n";
            for (int k=0 ; k<80 ; cout << "-", k++);
            cout << "\n\n";
        }
    void ctc()
    {
        hiline();
        printf ("\n\nClick to continue.......... \n\n");
        hiline();
        getch();
        clrscr();
    }
};
void main()
{
    gra gra;
    ari ari;
    log log;
    FILE *p,*u,*r,*ra;
    clrscr();
    p=fopen("c://turboc3//bin//project//Password.txt","r+");
    ra=fopen("c://turboc3//bin//project//Recans.txt","r+");
    r=fopen("c://turboc3//bin//project//Recovery.txt","r+");
    u=fopen("c://turboc3//bin//project//Username.txt","r+");
    char pas[44], user[44], reco[88] , recoa[44];
    devsta:

    fseek(p, 0 , 0);
    fscanf(p,"%s", &pas);
    fseek(u, 0 , 0);
    fscanf(u,"%s", &user);
    fseek(r, 0 , 0);
    fscanf(r,"%s", &reco);
    fseek(ra, 0 , 0);
    fscanf(ra,"%s", &recoa);
    fseek(ra, 0 , 0);
    fseek(p, 0 , 0);
    fseek(u, 0 , 0);
    fseek(r, 0 , 0);
    printf("%s\n", user);
    printf("%s\n", pas);
    printf("%s\n", reco);
    printf("%s\n", recoa);
    getch();
    int a;
    gra.hiline();
    printf ("\t\t\t\t  Welcome to\n\t\t\t\tLogin Screen!!\n\n");
    gra.asline();
    printf ("Click to continue.......... \n\n");
    gra.hiline();
    getch();
    clrscr();
    start:
    printf ("What you want to do?\n1-Login\n2-Reset using recovery question?\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    char inpass[44], inuser[44];
    if (a==1)
    {
        start2:
        gra.ctc();
        printf("\n\nEnter username : ");
        scanf ("%s", &inuser);
        printf("\n\nEnter password : ");
        scanf ("%s", &inpass);
        if (strcmp(inuser,user) && strcmp(inpass,pas))
        {
            printf("Wrong!!");
            gra.ctc();
            goto start2;
        }
        else
        {
            stay:
            gra.ctc();
            printf("\t\t\tWelcome\nYou have entered the correct credtionals!!\n");
            printf("1-Log off\n2-Change password\n\n");
            int i;
            scanf("%d", &i);
            if (i==1)
            {
                gra.ctc();
                goto logoff;
            }
            else if (i==2)
            {
                start3:
                gra.ctc();
                printf("\n\nEnter username : ");
                scanf ("%s", &inuser);
                printf("\n\nEnter password : ");
                scanf ("%s", &inpass);
                if (strcmp(inuser,user) && strcmp(inpass,pas))
                {
                    printf("Wrong!!");
                    gra.ctc();
                    printf("Wish to cont\n1-Yes\n2-No");
                    int y;
                    scanf("%d", &y);
                    if (y==1)
                    goto start3;
                    else
                    goto logoff;
                }
                else
                {
                    char newpass[44], newuser[44], cnewpass[44], newreco[88], newreca[88];
                    start4:
                    printf ("\nEnter new username : ");
                    scanf("%s", &newuser );
                    //printf("\nEnter new password : ");
                    printf ("\nEnter new recovery question : ");
                    scanf("%s", &newreco);
                    printf("\nEnter new recovery answer : ");
                    scanf("%s", &newreca);
                    printf ("\nEnter new password : ");
                    scanf("%s", &newpass);
                    printf("\nConfirm new password : ");
                    scanf("%s", &cnewpass);
                    if (strcmp(newpass, cnewpass))
                    {
                        printf("Passwords dont match\n");
                        gra.ctc();
                        goto start;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fclose(p);
                        fclose(u);
                        fclose(ra);
                        fclose(r);
                        p=fopen("c://turboc3//bin//project//Password.txt","w");
                        ra=fopen("c://turboc3//bin//project//Recans.txt","w");
                        r=fopen("c://turboc3//bin//project//Recovery.txt","w");
                        u=fopen("c://turboc3//bin//project//Username.txt","w");
                        printf("\n\nPassword and username successfully changed.....\n\n\n");
                        fseek(p, 0 , 0);
                        fprintf(p,"%s", newpass );
                        cout << "\nConfirmations:  ";
                        printf ("\nNew password : %s", newpass);
                        fseek(u, 0 , 0);
                        fprintf(u,"%s",newuser );
                        printf ("\nNew username : %s", newuser);
                        fseek(r, 0 , 0);
                        fprintf(r,"%s", newreco);
                        printf ("\nNew  recovery question : %s", newreco);
                        fseek(ra, 0 , 0);
                        fprintf(ra,"%s", newreca);
                        printf ("\nNew recovery answer : %s", newreca);
                        cout << "\nAll settings are saved....";
                        cout << "\nRedirecting .....";
                        gra.ctc();
                        fclose(p);
                        fclose(u);
                        fclose(ra);
                        fclose(r);
                        p=fopen("c://turboc3//bin//project//Password.txt","a+");
                        ra=fopen("c://turboc3//bin//project//Recans.txt","a+");
                        r=fopen("c://turboc3//bin//project//Recovery.txt","a+");
                        u=fopen("c://turboc3//bin//project//Username.txt","a+");
                        goto  devsta;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (a==2)
    {
        char enterrecoa[88];
        printf("\n\nRecovery question\n%s\nEnter recovery answer....\nDefault answer nil,\nQuestion nil\n", reco);
        scanf ("%s", &enterrecoa);
        if (strcmp(enterrecoa, recoa))
        {
            printf ("\n\nIncorrect!");
            gra.ctc();
            goto devsta;
        }
        else
        {
            fclose(p);
            fclose(u);
            fclose(ra);
            fclose(r);
            p=fopen("c://turboc3//bin//project//Password.txt","w");
            ra=fopen("c://turboc3//bin//project//Recans.txt","w");
            r=fopen("c://turboc3//bin//project//Recovery.txt","w");
            u=fopen("c://turboc3//bin//project//Username.txt","w");
            fseek(ra, 0 , 0);
            fseek(p, 0 , 0);
            fseek(u, 0 , 0);
            fseek(r, 0 , 0);
            fseek(ra, 0 , 0);
            fseek(p, 0 , 0);
            fseek(u, 0 , 0);
            fseek(r, 0 , 0);
            fprintf(p,"admin");
            fprintf(u,"admin");
            fprintf(r,"nil");
            fprintf(ra,"nil");
            printf("All user settings are back to default");
            fseek(ra, 0 , 0);
            fseek(p, 0 , 0);
            fseek(u, 0 , 0);
            fseek(r, 0 , 0);
            fclose(p);
            fclose(u);
            fclose(ra);
            fclose(r);
            p=fopen("c://turboc3//bin//project//Password.txt","a+");
            ra=fopen("c://turboc3//bin//project//Recans.txt","a+");
            r=fopen("c://turboc3//bin//project//Recovery.txt","a+");
            u=fopen("c://turboc3//bin//project//Username.txt","a+");
            gra.ctc();
            goto devsta;
        }
    }
    logoff:
    printf("exit");
    getch();
    fclose(p);
    fclose(u);
    fclose(ra);
    fclose(r);
}
```

Comment: There's SO much code here. Is this C++ or C? `void main` is not valid C++ but C doesn't have `iostream.h`. I think the fact it doesn't compile is probably right, but you should try to create a [mcve] so people can better help.

Comment: @Ashwin DS "Why"? Because Borland Turbo C++ is from an era when C++ was not yet a standard.

Comment: Can you view the contents of the .h file? That might help out.

Comment: @benc 2 i can't see how viewing a file could help.

Comment: @tas Its like c code in c++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't a simple "Hello World"-style program compile with Turbo C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c)

Comment: @AshwinDS What is this line supposed to do: `for (long long long long int a = 0; a<(w * 100000); a++);` ?? Probably replacing it by `for (long int a = 0; a<(w * 100000); a++);` should help. But this looks like an idle loop which brings its own problems.

Comment: The first C++ standard was in 1998. Turbo C++ was in the early 90s and doesn't even support STL

Comment: Please do not spam with unrelated language tags. C is a total different language than C++

Comment: @Swordfish - assuming the filename and line number reference are correct, we won't know unless we see the lines…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Change the beginning of your file from this:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "iostream.h"
#include "conio.h"
```

to this:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>    
#include "conio.h"

using namespace std;
```

2) Rename the class `log` to `mylog`, `log` is a standard function already defined via `#include <iostream>`.

3) Remove the calls to `clrscr()`, there is no such thing anymore.

4) Replace `for (long long long long int a = 0; a<(w * 100000); a++);` with `for (long int a = 0; a<(w * 100000); a++);`. What is this supposed to do? I doubt that this compiled with TurboC++

Then it will compile without errors.

Comment: I don't think the line `for (long long long long int a = 0; a<(w * 100000); a++)` will compile. And there are still a lot of standard conformance issues in the code

Comment: @phuclv fixed, but yes, the rest of the code remains questionable, even if it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Change your includes to refere to standard C++ Headers:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
```

and either use

```
using namespace std;
```

or prepend symbols from the standard library with `std::`.

Comment: Not yet resolved

Comment: @Ashwin DS care to clarify?

Comment: Itts the same error

Comment: @Ashwin DS There still are errors but not "Error C2371 'FILE': redefinition; different basic types" the one you mentioned in your question. And using the appropriate headers which put symbols of the standard library in namespace std definitely resolves C2371.