# C++ fatal error when try to compile: fatal error: string: No such file or directory

Tags: c++

I want to create a new class like below, and when I try to compile, an error occurs. How can I deal with such problem?

```
#ifndef _ACCOUNT_
#define _ACCOUNT_

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class CompteBancaire
{
private: // Sheltered members:
    string name; // Account holder
    unsigned long nr; // Account number
    double state; // State of the account
public: // Public interface:
    Account( const std::string& nom, unsigned long a, double b);
    Account( const std::string& nom );
  //  bool init( const string&, unsigned long, double);
    void display();

};
#endif
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't a simple "Hello World"-style program compile with Turbo C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c)

Comment: Compile with what? How? Where? When?

Comment: Not to nitpick, but Account is the wrong name for the constructor.

Comment: please how can i know which compiler am using.. i use code::blocks

Comment: Also exactly how do you start the compilation.  From within the IDE, from the command line..  These details matter.

Comment: If your compiler was not auto-detected, go to "Settings->Compiler and Debugger->Global Compiler settings->Toolchain executables", select the compiler you installed and press "Auto-detect". Check link http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Installing_a_supported_compiler

Comment: @learner My First question is What error ? And second is which Compiler ?

Comment: ||=== Build: Debug in constructeur (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) fatal error: string: No such file or directory|

Comment: Why are you using code::blocks in the first place?  Since it doesn't automatically install and configure a compiler, it's not the easiest choice for someone just starting.  What operating system are you using, there may be alternatives that work better "out of the box"

Comment: i just compile with simple programm but when i tru to add class to my project, error occur

Comment: Looks like you dont have the correct configuration. Compiler not be installed. If you are just using it to learn, try this online compiler https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php

Comment: i had compile with other project! how can i know if it is installed properly or not? (using code::blocks settings)

Comment: @learner `#include <iostream> int main() { std::cout <<  "Hello World"; }` -- If this doesn't compile, go to step 1 in the compiler installation and start over.

Comment: It looks to be a problem with `#include <string>`. Can you try this `#include <string.h>`?

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifndef _ACCOUNT_
#define _ACCOUNT_

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class CompteBancaire
{
private: // Sheltered members:
    string name; // Account holder
    unsigned long nr; // Account number
    double state; // State of the account
public: // Public interface:
    CompteBancaire( const std::string& nom, unsigned long a, double b);
    CompteBancaire( const std::string& nom );
  //  bool init( const string&, unsigned long, double);
    void display();

};
#endif
```

Comment: Rather than revising the code as an answer, you should edit the original question to look like this, and then delete this answer.

Comment: Yes.  But there is an `edit` link under your original question.  You are supposed to use that for code corrections.

Comment: thanks for your information .. i will use this option

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
```

and

> fatal error: string: No such file or directory

say you're missing an option to specify the directory to search for include files.  It's usually `-I`  That said, if code::blocks is set up property, it should take care of all this for you if you simply build from within the IDE.

Comment: what should i do

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming `Account( const std::string& nom, unsigned long a, double b)` and
 `Account( const std::string& nom)` to be a constructor. But it is not true. The constructor should have the same name as the class name. In your case constructor should have the name `CompteBancaire`

```
CompteBancaire(const std::string& nom, unsigned long a, double b);
CompteBancaire(const std::string& nom);
```

Make this change and compile, it should work.

Comment: What is the error now? Try adding `#include <iostream>`. I tried on this online compiler https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php with the change I mentioned and its working well.

Comment: when i add  #include <iostream> ... this error appear:     fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory|

Comment: Looks like you might be having some problem with the compiler installation. Can you try the code on online compiler and then go back to code blocks. Check this link http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/MinGW_installation

Comment: @learner -- Why didn't you simply start off by compiling the simplest of C++ programs, i.e. "Hello World".  There was no need to get into trying to create classes if you can't get a simple "Hello World" program to build correctly.

Comment: yes it compiles .. no problem with   "Hello World". it run correctly