# c++ program multiple declaraton error

Tags: syntax-error, turbo-c++

I am getting multiple declaration error in this c++ program

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main ()
{       clrscr();
    int a[10][10],r,q,i;
    cout<<"enter how many rows and colomn you want in the matrix:";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"enter the matrix \n";
    for(int r=0;r<n;++r)
    {
        for(int q=0;q<n;++q)
        {
            cin>>a[r][q];
        }

    }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   cout<<"\n the diagnol elements are:";
        cout<<a[n-i-1][i];
    }
    getch();
}
```

it is a program for finding diagnol elements in a matrix

Comment: can not reproduce, please provide [mcve]

Comment: [Wandbox example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2YMjTwuvKCsm3Q1q)

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't a simple “Hello World”-style program compile with Turbo C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c) That is a simple example, but there are many differences between C++ and Turbo C++ that you could be tripping over. My recommendation is for you to divide and conquer. Back up your source file, then start removing pieces of the code to help you narrow down what exactly is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have already declared the `r`, `q`, `i` as `int` at line 5 as below:

```
int a[10][10],r,q,i;
              ^^^^^
```

While your three for loops, again re-declares for e.g. like this:

```
for(int r=0;r<n;++r)
    ^^^
```

So it re-declares the same variable in above case it's `r`, while the other for loop `q` and `i` which is not allowed.

Two ways to solve the problem:

a. Either you remove int from your for loop.
b. Either you remove declaration of variables used in for loop from line 5.

Comment: I believe declare variable inside for loop would not result in that error. [wandbox example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aJ0gafyLQ1npbw1O)

Answer (score 0):

The only issue i am seeing is, you are not declaring the variable "n" . Other than that, everything seems to be fine.