# What's the prototype/library for getline();

Tags: c++

I want to use getline(); function in c++. I have put the #include at the header. But i got error that said "Function 'getline' should have a prototype". Is the library wrong ? Or i need another library? 
Here is my code

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream.h>

void main(){
    char word;
    ofstream file;

    file.open("code.txt");
    file.close();

    while(getline(file,word))
    {
        cout<<word<<"\n";
    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Why `file.close();` before using `getline()` ? It should be after.

Comment: `char word;` makes no sense. Do you want to store a character or a word?

Comment: `main` must return `int`, not `void`.

Comment: "iostream.h" is an ancient pre-standardization header, as is "fstream.h".  "string.h" is the C header that has `strcpy` and friends.  The correct headers are "iostream", "fstream", and "string".

Comment: Including `<string>` and `<iostream>` will get you a `getline` function, but it won't take a `char` as its second argument.

Comment: @MilesBudnek are you knocking my circa 1989 Borland C/C++ setup? (`:)`

Comment: My Turbo C++ sense is tingling so I'll just drop [Why doesn't a simple “Hello World”-style program compile with Turbo C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c) here as a warning for some of the problems you're going to run into.

Comment: Also check if `file.open` succeeded or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `getline()` is for `getline(ifstream, string)` not `getline(ofstream, char)`. Thus, your code should look more like this:

```
string word;
ifstream myFile("code.txt");

while(getline(myFile,word))
    cout<< word<< "\n";
```