# How does delete operator work with pointers in c?

Tags: c++

How does delete operator work in C++?

```
int *ptr = new int[2];
delete[] ptr;
```

How does delete operator know the amount of memory allocated, since ptr is just a int pointer and increment-ing(++) it would simply make it point to the next location in the continuously allocated structure.

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour. You meant `delete[] ptr`.

Comment: First of all, it should be `delete[]`. Second of all, it's the C++ compiler's and C++ library's job to know how much to delete, and is something that someone writing a C++ compiler has no reason to care about, at all. That's the C++ library's job.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How does delete “know” the size of the operand array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197675/how-does-delete-know-the-size-of-the-operand-array)? Also, note that your code has Undefined Behaviour - you have to `delete[]` what you allocated with `new[]` and `delete` what you allocated with `new`.

Comment: There is no delete operator in C.

Comment: Thanks for your time everyone :)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik C++ library's job..hmm. Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Blastfurnace No, that mistake was tangential to the question, so fixing it was the right thing to do. There's a reason I pointed it out in the comments.

Comment: What's to "elaborate"? There's nothing to elaborate here. The C++ library knows how to do it, and that's all I need to know. In the ~30 years I've been coding C++, I don't recall a single time when I found the need to know the exact mechanical details of how this works. And even if I did, it would be just a simple matter of looking at the compiled code and see how a particular `delete[]` works.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Sorry if I hurt you in any way but I was just curious enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocators typically hide allocation information just *before* the pointer in question. The allocation includes that space, but the pointer is moved after it so you don't access/modify it. This is part of why writing to a pointer at a negative index breaks things so badly.

As noted in the comments, your code is broken as written, since you used `delete ptr;`, not `delete[] ptr;`; only the latter knows to look for the information needed to destruct the whole array, not just a single element.

Comment: So what would happen if I would increment ptr by 2 bytes and then performed the delete operation?

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow What happens when you pass a totally arbitrary/random pointer to `delete`? You get undefined behaviour, of course! Why would you do that?

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow: [Nasal demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica So that would basically depend on how the library is described...Is there any way I can read the library?

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow Many standard library implementations are open source, yes. But, honestly, you're wasting your time. Don't `delete` invalid pointers. It's never going to do anything useful, is it?

Comment: Actually, I was curious enough to know how those libraries actually work. So it would be great if you could guide me accordingly

Comment: As I say, you can go look up the source code if you want.

Comment: Where would it be in the case of Turbo C++?

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow re _"...Turbo C++..."_ have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c  And please pick a different compiler.

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow Turbo C++ is (a) not open source, and (b) **antique**. It predates the very first version of the C++ standard by some ten years. It's thirty years old. It's time to move on.

Comment: I wish I could have...

Comment: When you have to load up a _DOS emulator_ to use your tool, something's wrong.

Comment: My college prefers Turbo C++ for some reason.

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow cheaper than updating their courses - problem is calling it C++, Turbo C++ is really a different language.

Comment: @RichardCritten and maybe even easier perhaps..just as more than 50% of the code that is actually in use is written in COBOL.