# Why am I getting error ''Type name expected' error in my C++ code?

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I am using Turbo C to write the below code, but I am getting one error and two warnings:

> 1. warning in line 30: Functions containing while are not expanded inline

> 2. error in line 37: Type name expected

> 3. warning in line 48: Functions containing while are not expanded inline

How can I fix them?

I guess the compiler is Borland.

```cpp
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

class second
{
protected:
    int sec;

public:
    second()
    {
        sec = 0;
    }

    void getsec()
    {
        cout << "\n enter the second time:";
        cin >> sec;
    }
};

class min : public second
{
protected:
    int mini;

public:
    min()
    {
        mini = 0;
    }

    void convert()
    {
        getsec();
        while (sec >= 60)
        {
            mini = mini + 1;
        }
    }
};

class hour : public min
{
protected:
    int hr;

public:
    hour()
    {
        hr = 0;
    }

    void convert1()
    {
        convert();
        while (mini >= 60)
        {
            mini = mini - 60;
            hr = hr + 1;
        }
        cout << "hr:" << hr << "\t mini" << mini << "\t sec" << sec;
    }
};

int main()
{
    clrscr();
    hour h;
    h.convert1();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: which is line 37?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't a simple "Hello World"-style program compile with Turbo C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c)

Comment: @RichardCritten Doubtful

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica agreed but also for this reason: _"...This is intended to be a standard dupe redirect for questions asking about Turbo C++ problems. Many of these questions tend to be shot down quickly with only a brief explanation in comments, while they can really use a proper answer...."_

Comment: @Me Why did you revert the improved formatting?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 line 37 is-   { 
protected: 
int hr; 
public:

Comment: That's four lines.

Comment: To be fair to @Richard, I can't reproduce this [after "fixing" the most obvious Turbo C++ isms](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e6093ced465b764). Given its location in your code, I was expecting the problem to remain with an otherwise compliant program, but instead it looks like one of your names (either `min` or `hr`, probably the former) is conflicting with something from Turbo C++'s headers. Without access to that, nobody's going to be able to reliably help, I'm afraid.

Comment: As such, though I'm still not prepared to accept that other post as a dupe, I recommend reading it, because you may not get an answer to this question.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: The "type name expected" is probably due to `min` clashing with a macro,  the best fix to this (besides changing the compiler of course) is probably to call the class something else

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the two warnings; they are just warnings. You are implementing your class methods to be inlined, but the compiler won't inline methods with `while` loops in them, so they won't be inlined in the final executable. That is ok; inlining is just an optimization, and the methods with still work. But that being said, you don't need to use any `while` loops in this code at all. You can use simple integer arithmetic instead, via the `/` (division) and `%` (modulus) operators, when calculating your values.

I do see a few other problems with your code, though.

You need to change `<iostream.h>` to `<iostream>`, and then prefix `cin` and `cout` with `std::`.

`<conio.h>` is a non-standard header, and you should avoid using it at all. There isn't any standard C++ replacement for `clrscr()`, and you would have to resort to platform-specific APIs (see [Clearing the Screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/clearing-the-screen) for Windows), but you can use `std::cin.get()` as a replacement for `getch()`.

`min::convert()` gets stuck in an endless loop of the user enters a value >= 60. You are not decrementing `sec` on each loop iteration, like you do in `hour::convert1()`.

The identifier `min` is already used in the C runtime library and the C++ standard library, for the `min()` macro and `std::min()` algorithm, so you should rename your `min` class to something more unique.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdlib>

class seconds
{
protected:
    int secs;

public:
    seconds()
    {
        secs = 0;
    }

    void getsecs()
    {
        std::cout << "\n enter the time in seconds:";
        std::cin >> secs;
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
};

class minutes : public seconds
{
protected:
    int mins;

public:
    minutes()
    {
        mins = 0;
    }

    void convert()
    {
        getsecs();
        mins = secs / 60;
        secs %= 60;
    }
};

class hours : public minutes
{
protected:
    int hrs;

public:
    hours()
    {
        hrs = 0;
    }

    void convert1()
    {
        convert();
        hrs = mins / 60;
        mins %= 60;
    }

    void show()
    {
        std::cout << "hrs:" << hrs << "\t mins" << mins << "\t secs" << secs;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::system("clr");

    hours h;
    h.convert1();
    h.show();

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You sure this works with Turbo C++? Also `stdlib.h` should be `cstdlib`.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang I can't guarantee it, but most of it should work in such an old compiler, this is pretty basic stuff

Comment: @RemyLebeau IIRC in old MS-DOS turbo c++ you need `#include <iostream.h>` btw in case `std::system("clr");` does not work there is still the BIOS setting of mode 3 (80x25 text)

Answer (score 0):

OK-- I got it. I mistakenly typed 'public main' instead of 'public min' in line 38. Also I removed one while statement and modified it a bit as the code was not showing output for seconds input above 60 seconds.

Here is the working modified (somewhat) code.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

class second
{
protected:
    int sec;

public:
    second()
    {
        sec = 0;
    }

    void getsec()
    {
        cout << "\n enter the second time:";
        cin >> sec;
    }
};

class min : public second
{
protected:
    int mini;

public:
    min()
    {
        mini = 0;
    }

    void convert()
    {
        getsec();
        mini = sec / 60;
        sec %= 60;
    }
};

class hour : public min
{
protected:
    int hr;

public:
    hour()
    {
        hr = 0;
    }

    void convert1()
    {
        convert();
        while (mini >= 60)
        {
            mini = mini - 60;
            hr = hr + 1;
        }
        cout << "hr:" << hr << "\t mini" << mini << "\t sec" << sec;
    }
};

int main()
{
    clrscr();
    hour h;
    h.convert1();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks all (especially @Remy Lebeau) for your help.

Comment: The typo you describe is not present in the code you provided in your question, which means you didn't provide your real code from the beginning. And you had another typo in this new code, too. And why didn't you get rid of the `while` loop in `convert1()`, like I demonstrated? And you still need to learn how to format your code so people can read it.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau This is the code that i wanted to run and i have it in a pdf file. But my Turbo C didn't had a copy paste option so i manually typed the code in it. Also, i got the desired result by eliminating one while loop so i kept the other the way it was. Thanks.