# Create a vector with repeated entries of each Element

Tags: c++

I want to expand a given vector by repeating every entry three times. For example, if the vector is `[5,7]`. The output vector should be `[5 5 5 7 7 7]`

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<vector.h>

int main(void)
{
   std::vector<int> x;
   x.push_back(5);
   x.push_back(7);
   x.insert(x.end(), x.begin(), x.begin() + 1);

return 0;
}
```

This didnt work out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Judging from the `.h` suffixes, are you using an outdated C++ compiler?  Recommended: [Why doesn't a simple “Hello World”-style program compile with Turbo C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44863062/9716597)

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look. Ignoring this, is the insert function written properly to do the purpose?  Thanks

Comment: The insert line has undefined behavior, unfortunately, since `x.begin()` and `x.begin() + 1` are iterators into the vector itself.  See the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert).

Comment: It would be simpler and more efficient to create a new vector instead of modifying the existing one

Comment: @Damien I agree. What would be a cleaner way to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach is to loop over the vector and create a new one:

```
std::vector<int> vec{5, 7};

// create a new vector
std::vector<int> new_vec;
new_vec.reserve(vec.size() * 3);

for (auto elem : vec) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        new_vec.push_back(elem);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how simple code you want, but for example this works.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

int main(void)
{
   std::vector<int> x;
   x.push_back(5);
   x.push_back(7);
   for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = x.end(); it != x.begin(); )
   {
      it--;
      it = x.insert(it, 2, *it);
   }

   // print the vector to check
   for (size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) std::cout << x[i] << " ";
   std::cout << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this could help you achieve that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> RepeateEntryNumberOfTimes(std::vector<T> input, std::uint16_t numberOfTimes)
{
    std::vector<T> result;

    std::for_each(input.begin(), input.end(), [&result, numberOfTimes](T item){ 
        for(std::uint16_t numberOfReps = 0; numberOfReps != numberOfTimes; ++numberOfReps)
        {
            result.push_back(item);
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

See godbolt example: https://godbolt.org/z/ns9o3b

Answer (score 1):

Your code has problem since it inserting elements to same vector.
Modification of vector invalidates old iterators, so your code has undefined behavior.

Even ignoring this error, logic of your code doesn't seem to do what you are expecting.

```cpp
template<typename In, typename Out>
Out replicate_elements(In b, In e, size_t n, Out o)
{
    while(b != e) {
        o = std::fill_n(o, n, *b++);
    }
    return o;
}

std::vector<int> foo(const std::vector<int>& x)
{
    std::vector<int> r;
    r.reserve(x.size() * 3);
    replicate_elements(x.begin(), x.end(), 3, std::back_inserter(r));
    return r;
}
```

https://www.godbolt.org/z/zvE5TG