# Error comes out with precision, how can I get rid from this?

Tags: c++, c, c++11

Answer comes wrong when using decimal places!

I'm running the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<math.h>

main()

{

float x,y,div;

printf("Enter two numbers x,y \n");

scanf("%f%f",&x, &y);

div=x/y;

printf("div=%12.10f\n",div;

return 0;

}
```

After running, when I put x=1 and y=3 then answer comes 0.3333333433, but answer should be 0.3333333333. Why this error comes ? How can I get rid from this kind of error ? Please help.

Comment: Turbo C++? Which year is this? :)

Comment: `printf("%12.10f %a\n", div, div);` might help you understand what's going on.

Comment: You have run into the limits of 32-bit floating point precision. Only 6 significant digits are guaranteed to be accurate, so your best bet is to use `"%.6g"` for your format specifier.

However, should you wish to round-trip the float, use `"%.9g"` (ie, such that scanf will return the same float).

For double, the relevant numbers are 15 and 17.

Comment: plese only tag what you actually use. It cannot be C and C++, and Turbo C++s support stopped before C++11 came out

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/ for why Sourav is asking "what year is this?"

Comment: Required reading: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0):

A `float` cannot represent every real number exactly, only about 2<sup>32</sup> of them. 1.0f/3.0f does not get saved as 0.3333333333, instead a nearby value is saved: 0.3333333432674407958984375 - a  [dyadic rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational).

Printing that out to 10 decimal places after the `.` is  0.3333333433.

> How can I get rid from this kind of error ?

Use higher precision types like `double` for this example.  Still a like issue will occur with higher precision output `"%22.20f"`.

... or instead change your expectations of using binary floating point to form decimal answers.

.... wait for a next version of [C2X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x) which may have decimal floating point.

Comment: Re “may have decimal floating point”: That’s not going to represent ⅓ exactly either.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True, yet OP's goal was to print a rounded value - not exact.  With common FP, two roundings occurred in OP's code (first one was binary in the quotient calculation), 2nd was in printing with a decimal rounding.  With decimal FP, both roundings still occur and risk the usual issue about _double roduning_.  Being both  in decimal, the effect remains but to a lesser surprising extent.