# How to make difference between function with and without argument when using inheritance in C++ in modern compilers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, inheritance, turbo-c++

I am learning C++ inheritance. Below is a program of the same. Here two classes are there `Number` and `ExNumber`. `Number` is base class. I am getting error in second `input` definition of `ExNumber`, the one which has `setData` with `int` as argument. I got to know that this declaration will work on Turbo C++ compiler from my teacher. This does not work in my visual studio code. He teaches for turbo C++. I need help with how one should declare the definition in modern compilers. Thank you. The error I get it `type name is not alowed`. This error is for `setData` in second input function. Thanks in advance.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Number
{
    int no;
    public:
        void setData()
        {
            cout << "\nNo: ";
            cin >> no;
        }

        void setdata(int a)
        {
            no = a;
        }

        int getData()
        {
            return no;
        }

        void display()
        {
            cout << "\nRoll  No:" << no;

        }
};

class  ExNumber : Number
{
    public:
        void input()
        {
            setData();
        }

        void input (int)
        {
            setData( int);
        }

        void output()
        {
            display();
        }

        void table();
        int isPrime();
};

void ExNumber :: table()
{
    int i = 1,n = getData();
    cout << "\nTable\n";
    while(i <= 10)
    {
        cout << "   " << n*i;
        i++;
    }
}

int ExNumber :: isPrime()
{
    int i = 2, n = getData();
    while(i < n)
    {
        if( n % i == 0)
            break;
        i++;
    }
    return (i == n) ;
}

int main()
{
    ExNumber p;
    p.input(23);
    p.output();
    p.table();
    ExNumber q;
    q.input();
    q.output();
    if(q.isPrime() == 0)
        cout << "\nNot";
    cout << " Prime";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how functions are defined and called?

Comment: *I got to know that this declaration will work on Turbo C++ compiler from my teacher*. You need to know that, *TurboC++* is called *the one which cannot be spoken of* here

Comment: Note that in `Number`,  you define one function `void setData()` and another function `void setdata(int a)` but no function `void setData(int a)`. In C++, capitalization matters.

Comment: yes sir. but The way my teacher has given. it works only on turbo c++. not on my visual studio, he said its compiler incompatibility. he asked me to use turbo C++. But I want to know how to on visual studio.

Comment: It will never work in Visual Studio. It is not supposed to in the first place! I am sure it does NOT work in TurboC++ too. If it does... god bless you, you are on your own ;)

Comment: It's also weird to me that `ExNumber::isPrime` returns an `int` instead of a `bool`. C++ has a boolean primitive type, why not use it?

Comment: he teaches in turboc++. and uses return 1 or 0 instead of bool. I know its unconventional
i want to know how setdata should be called in order to work

Comment: Change your definition to `void input(int a)` and call `setData` using `setData(a)`. This is the standard c++ way to define and call functions. Please, if you can, just change your compiler, and if he ain't a college teacher, for god's sake stop learning from him!

Comment: thanks a lot sir. It worked. He is not my college teacher. I will leave him soon. Tired of his primitiveness I stopped using turboc++. Thank you so much to help. In debt.....

Comment: Handy reading: [Why doesn't a simple “Hello World”-style program compile with Turbo C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c).