# wchar.h no such file or directory

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, mingw

I've been trying to run simple c++ program

```
#include<iostream.h>
        
void main(){
    cout<<"helloworld";
}
```

and the error I get is :

```
 In file included from d:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\postypes.h:40:0,                   
                 from d:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iosfwd:40,                              
                 from d:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ios:38,                                 
                 from d:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,                             
                 from d:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,                            
                 from my.cpp:1:                                                                         
d:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:44:19: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory 
 #include <wchar.h>                                                                                      
                   ^                                                                                     
compilation terminated."
```

anyone know how to fix it ,I'm using the mingw to compile it.

Comment: Why not `#include <iostream>` and `int main()`?

Comment: Possibly related: [Why doesn't a simple “Hello World”-style program compile with Turbo C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c) though it seems you may be getting the inverse.

Comment: This is the result I expect to see from the given code and what appears to be a GCC 6.3-based compiler: https://godbolt.org/z/b9hrzz

Comment: on Big Sur, i had this problem while compiling with g++. i used clang++ instead, worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your MinGW is broken. Also, GCC 6.3.0 is very **old**.

Try a more recent MinGW or even better MinGW-w64.

A standalone build is available from http://winlibs.com/ with GCC 10.2.0 (both for Windows 32-bit and 64-bit).