# C++ VCL Custom TEdit control with text transformation

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder, vcl

I am pondering about creating a custom `TEdit` control that transforms the text (set via Text property) depending on the current font charset.
I guess that I need to overwrite the `OnPaint` event and work with the WinAPI (`CreateText`) to display a text different to the actual text.

En detail: The text displayed is not the real text of the `TEdit` control. If the application reads the control's `Text` property, the original value should be returned, not the displayed text transformed depending on the current charset.

I would be thankful for a simple example/entry point, how that kind of a method/event would have to look like.

Comment: As the toolkit you want to use is about 14 years old (since it was last updated) we might not be able to help.  Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c for alternatives.

Comment: @RichardCritten "*the toolkit you want to use is about 14 years old*" - I assume you are referring to the old Borland C++ command line compiler? The VCL doesn't exist in that product, it is part of C++Builder instead, which is very much still in production (its latest version was released just 2 months ago).

Comment: @RichardCritten: You shouldn't comment if you're not familiar with the topic. C++ Builder is very much alive today, with a new version being recently released (within the past couple of months), so your comment about *14 years* is totally wrong. There is no reason to be looking for an alternative. You may want to do some research.