# including iostream showing a syntax error in turbo C++

Tags: c++, iostream, turbo-c++

I am just new to C++. I am getting an error while compiling this program in `Turbo C++`. Can someone tell me what exactly is it saying and what's the solution to this. It gives error in the include statement. I don't know what to do...

[image: Code and error]

Sorry to enter the image but `Turbo C++` doesn't let you copy the text of the errors coming...

Comment: Change `iostream` to `iostream.h` and remove `using namespace std;`. (Better change your compiler instead.)

Comment: What the error message is really telling you is that you are using a prehistoric C++ compiler that's been obsolete since last century, and offers very little of value to anyone who wants to learn modern C++.

Comment: @brc-dd Okkay. That worked for me. As far as compiler is concerned, I tried using `vscode` but the error comes that the path is not up to the required place . (I don't know anything more about it !) I tried fixing it but no gain...

Comment: @UtkarshSahu -- You should stop using Turbo C++ and figure out how to fix the compiler you were using.   There is nothing syntactically wrong with the code you had, but instead you are now fighting with a dinosaur of a compiler that doesn't recognize perfectly valid, simple, C++ code of the modern era.  Turbo C++ is 35 years old and hasn't been updated, maybe in 20 years.  Also, `vscode` is not a compiler, it is an IDE.  The compiler being used underneath all of that is probably `g++`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't a simple "Hello World"-style program compile with Turbo C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c)

Comment: Turbo C++, the DOS variant belongs in a museum. Really, just use a modern compiler and IDE